# Discretization Error amplification in a numerical scheme written in Python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, discrete-mathematics, differential-equations

I am using python for my numerical method projects and at this point I am facing a problem that is mostly related to the way I am coding with python.

So I wrote a code on Python 2.7.5 to solve numerically an Ordinary differential equation (1D Diffusion equation - stationnary - a constant diffusion coefficient = 1 and a second member used in order to have sin(pi*x) as a solution).

Basically, the numerical scheme discretize the equation and the discretized solution is evaluted on the points of the 1D seperated by a fixed step `dx`.

A simple theoretical study shows that if `dx` tends to 0 then the difference between the constructed solution of the diff equation and the exact solution ,called `Err` goes to 0.

When running my code, I found that for very small `dx`, `Err` doesn't stagnate at the machine precision error (the expected behaviour) but goes up for several magnitude orders.

Is it a problem in the precision/round managment of Python for very small numbers ?

I tried to write the problem in different ways (Matrix, Loops, Matrix inversion technices) but the same phenomenon happened.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve import spsolve

Err=[]

N=np.array([10,20,40,80,100,800,2000,5000,10000,50000,100000,600000,900000])
#Loop on the number of points used for the discretization of the 1D domain   

for Nx in N:

    dx=(1.0)/Nx# fixed distance between two consecutive points in the domain
    x = np.linspace(dx,1.0-dx,Nx-1)# points of the domains


    #Matrix contruction used for the resolution 
    data = [np.ones(Nx-1), -2*np.ones(Nx-1), np.ones(Nx-1)]# Diagonal terms
    offsets = np.array([-1, 0, 1])# Their positions
    LAP = sp.dia_matrix((data, offsets), shape=(Nx-1, Nx-1))#
    f = -np.pi**2*np.sin(np.pi*x)*dx**2#constant Second member 
    sol_num = spsolve(LAP,f)#Resolution of the matrix system 

    sol_ana=np.sin(np.pi*x)#The exact solution

    Err.append((np.absolute((sol_ana-sol_num))).max())

plt.figure()
plt.plot(N,Err,N,N**float(-2),'--')
plt.legend(['Err','Theoretical asymptotic behaviour'])
plt.xlabel('dx')
plt.ylabel('Err')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Cross post from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2711890/115115. Probably the wrong venue, scientific computing would be more appropriate. Explore the condition numbers of the near-singular matrices `LAP`.

Comment: Indeed. At first I was suspecting a coding error or artefact.